# How to get ssmtp to map local user to email address for the To: field

Tags: email, ssmtp

I have a simple `ssmtp` setup.

The command `echo test | mail -s "testing" username` always results in me trying to send an email to `username@hostname` which always fails.

I am thus trying to map the local username to a specific email address.

How do I do this?

I tried `/etc/aliases`, but

```
$ sudo newaliases 
newaliases: Aliases are not used in sSMTP
```

Then I tried

```
$ cat /etc/mail.rc 
alias root root<xxx@yyy.com>
alias username username<xxx@yyy.com>
```

But it still isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: SSMTP does not use /etc/aliases see https://possiblelossofprecision.net/?p=591

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have struggled a bit with `ssmtp` too. The first thing I learned is that the aliases mechanism **does not** work with the plain `mail` program; I have to use `mailx` from the package `bsd-mailx` — never knew why. So before starting to change configurations around check with it.

Anyway, as a reference, I have a working `ssmtp` setup like the following:

1. file  `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`:

   ```
   #
   # Config file for sSMTP sendmail
   #
   # The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
   # Make this empty to disable rewriting.
   root=romano@mymail.domain.com

   # The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no 
   # MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
   mailhub=mymailserver.mymail.domain.com:25

   # Where will the mail seem to come from?
   rewriteDomain=mymail.domain.com

   # The full hostname
   hostname=myhostname.mymail.domain.com
   # Use SSL/TLS before starting negotiation 
   UseTLS=No
   #UseSTARTTLS=Yes
   #
   # Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
   # YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address
   # NO - Use the system generated From: address
   FromLineOverride=NO
   ```
2. file `/etc/ssmtp/revaliases/`

   ```
   # sSMTP aliases
   # 
   # Format:   local_account:outgoing_address:mailhub
   #
   # Example: root:your_login@your.domain:mailhub.your.domain[:port]
   # where [:port] is an optional port number that defaults to 25.
   #
   root:romano@mymail.domain.com
   romano:romano@mymail.domain.com
   postmaster:romano@mymail.domain.com
   ```

and now it works:

```
[romano:~] % mailx -v root
Subject: test
test
.
Cc: 
[<-] 220 mymailserver.mymail.domain.com ESMTP my mail server
[->] HELO myhostname.mymail.domain.com
[<-] 250 mymailserver.mymail.domain.com
[->] MAIL FROM:<romano@mymail.domain.com>
[<-] 250 2.1.0 Ok
[->] RCPT TO:<romano@mymail.domain.com>
[<-] 250 2.1.5 Ok
[->] DATA
[<-] 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
[->] Received: by myhostname.mymail.domain.com (sSMTP sendmail emulation); Fri, 03 Jul 2015 13:25:52 +0200
[->] From: "Romano Giannetti" <romano@mymail.domain.com>
[->] Date: Fri, 03 Jul 2015 13:25:52 +0200
[->] To: root
[->] Subject: test
[->] 
[->] test
[->] .
[<-] 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as BF1CB3BC050
[->] QUIT
[<-] 221 2.0.0 Bye
```

*Notice that domains, hostnames etc. are scrambled for privacy here (so there can be typoes)*.

Comment: any idea if the rewriteDomain attribute works with gmail?

Comment: @qodeninja, no, never tried...

Comment: Thanks, it worked after I added `root:user1@example.com:mail.example.com` line to `/etc/ssmtp/revaliases` file.

Comment: This only works for the *From*-address. If you want to change the *To*-address you have to edit `/etc/mail.rc`