# Postfix to send email using gmail address

Tags: command-line, email, postfix, mail, gmail

I'm using postfix and `mail` from `mailutils` to send email using my gmail address through command line in Ubuntu. 
It works fine when I provide both from and to address like below:

```
mail -s "Some random subject" -a "From: username@gmail.com" username1@gmail.com
```

But I need to configure to send email from default gmail address without specifying from address everytime. How can I do that?

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the sender address `mail` uses by default in your `~/.mailrc` file – create it if it doesn't exist yet – with the following line:

```
set from="username@gmail.com"
```

If this helps you, please also upvote [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/732782/507051) where I got it from and where you can get a configuration example.

Answer (score 0):

A general way of adding options you want to be default to a command-line program is an alias, see: [How do I create a permanent Bash alias?](https://askubuntu.com/q/17536/507051)
In your case this would be a line

```
alias mail='mail -a "From: username@gmail.com"'
```

added to either your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases` file.

Comment: I thought of this solution, but I have different use cases. I'm using other applications as well I should be able to send email using that application commands as well.

Comment: @harsha If you give an option a second time it overwrites the first one for many programs, I didn't try it with `mail` though.