# Unable to send mail externally using mailx on ubuntu 16.0.4

Tags: mail

Unable to send email to external users using mailx command. Could you please help me with the steps to configure mailx command in ubuntu.

Comment: What is working? What is not? What have you tried? Do you get any error messages (please post them if so)? - Update your original post with the info.

Comment: Is this useful to you: https://askubuntu.com/q/732677/57576 ?

Comment: PFB output  hima@hima-VirtualBox:~$ mailx -s "" abc@xyz.com
Cc: acd@yzf.com
Null message body; hope that's ok

send-mail: Authorization failed (534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 o206-v6sm12467503oif.7 - gsmtp)
Can't send mail: sendmail process failed with error code 1

Comment: @Himavanth You put your own username and password in place?