# Mail sent successfully but failed to be received

Tags: email, postfix

I tried to send mail to personal email

```
me@host:~$ mail -s "Sending a Tesing" gcpu.whisper@gmail.com
Cc: gcpu.whisper@gmail.com

This is a testing mail.
```

The records :

```
me@host:~$ tail -n 15 /var/spool/mail/gaowei | sed "s/$USER/me/g"
Subject: Sending a Tesing
To: <gcpu.whisper@gmail.com>
Cc: <gcpu.whisper@gmail.com>
X-Mailer: mail (GNU Mailutils 3.4)
Message-Id: <20190317063817.D05E5600B53@alpha>
Date: Sun, 17 Mar 2019 14:38:17 +0800 (CST)
From: me <me@host>


This is a testing mail.



--D05E5600B53.1552804699/host--
```

It seems that my email has been sent successfully.

Unfortunately ,  gmail does not receive such an email either  in junk box.

What's the problem with my usage of mail?

Comment: Any assistance with this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/732782/57576 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to send a email through the command line on (Ubuntu Desktop)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732677/unable-to-send-a-email-through-the-command-line-on-ubuntu-desktop)