# sSMTP, mail, aliases

Tags: mail, alias, ssmtp

I setup ssmtp to send email messages from my Ubuntu server to an external email address.

Using the mail command of the mailutils package, I am able to receive emails from my server sent via :

```
$echo test | mail -s test remote@mydomain.com
```

What I want to do now, is to send any message addressed to user root (like alerts and so on) to remote@mydomain.com.

```
$echo test | mail -s test root
```

One of the most promissing solutions I found so far is :

[sSMTP revaliases, aliases and mail.rc](https://possiblelossofprecision.net/?p=591)

As ssmtp is not able to forward and alias, the article tells one to use mail to alias addresses.
But this also doesn't work. Indeed, I do not even have an /etc/mail.rc file in my filesystem.

It seems like the email has left the host, but never reaches the remote mail address.

```
Apr 19 19:46:16 hostname sSMTP[1160]: Creating SSL connection to host
Apr 19 19:46:16 hostname sSMTP[1160]: SSL connection using ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Apr 19 19:46:17 hostname sSMTP[1160]: Sent mail for remote@mydomain.com (221 2.0.0 Bye) uid=0 username=root outbytes=459
```

So far the summary. Now to the Question :

How to setup ssmtp and mail so that

```
$echo test | mail -s test root
```

will successfully send an email sent to root to an alias of root ?

Comment: Are you trying to send mail to the `root` user of the system that it is on?  If so, it is just `echo test | mail -s test root@localhost`

Comment: `echo test | mail -s test root@localhost`   results in   `Apr 19 20:22:58 hostname sSMTP[1270]: RCPT TO:<root@localhost> (504 5.5.2 <root@localhost>: Recipient address rejected: need fully-qualified address)`

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/407876/289128  Chances are your `myorigin` of `/etc/postfix/main.cf` is not configured properly

Comment: Change to msmtp...

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed for me with the answer at [How to get ssmtp to map local user to email address for the To: field](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643873/how-to-get-ssmtp-to-map-local-user-to-email-address-for-the-to-field)

In summary, the problem was that I was using the `mailutils` package. Switching to `bsd-mailx` (which also provides `/usr/bin/mail`) allowed for me to customize `/etc/mail.rc` to map the `To` address with `alias root root<me@example.com>`

Some further context:

My goal was to do the above using Fastmail as my SMTP server, sending to my own Fastmail account. When running `echo 'test' | mail -s "Test" root`, I would see the following in the ssmtp logs:

```
$ sudo journalctl -t sSMTP -f
Dec 26 21:20:55 server.lan sSMTP[3898845]: Creating SSL connection to host
Dec 26 21:20:55 server.lan sSMTP[3898845]: SSL connection using ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Dec 26 21:20:56 server.lan sSMTP[3898845]: 551 5.7.1 Not authorised to send from this header address
```

I couldn't find anything useful for that specific error Fastmail was returning. To troubleshoot, I tried switching to a gmail account. In that case, Google accepted my email, and it was visible in my user's "sent" messages, but I quickly got a bounce message:

```
DNS Error: 13562819 DNS type 'mx' lookup of server.lan responded with code NXDOMAIN Domain name not found: server.lan
```

And, looking at the message source:

```
Return-Path: <example@gmail.com>
Received: from gmail.com ([MY-IP-ADDRESS-REDACTED])
        by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id az14sm13499775qkb.97.2021.12.27.06.12.13
        for <root@server.lan>
        (version=TLS1_3 cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 bits=256/256);
        Mon, 27 Dec 2021 06:12:14 -0800 (PST)
Message-ID: <61c9c9be.1c69fb81.e5f1.caae@mx.google.com>
From: root <example@gmail.com>
X-Google-Original-From: "root" <root@gmail.com>
Received: by gmail.com (sSMTP sendmail emulation); Mon, 27 Dec 2021 09:12:12 -0500
Date: Mon, 27 Dec 2021 09:12:12 -0500
To: <root@server.lan>
X-Mailer: mail (GNU Mailutils 3.7)

test
```

So, clearly Google was accepting the email, then trying to send to `root@server.lan` which didn't exist. In contrast, Fastmail does the smarter thing of checking the To address *before* accepting the email, avoiding the need to generate a bounce. I just wish their error message was clearer and documented somewhere!

With the above in place, I now get the following headers (triggered by running a `zfs scrub` on a pool where zfs sends emails on completion):

```
From: "root" <root@example.com>
Date: Mon, 27 Dec 2021 09:24:06 -0500
To: root<andrew@example.com>
Subject: ZFS scrub_finish event for bpool on fileserver.lan
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="ANSI_X3.4-1968"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Message-ID: <cmu-lmtpd-1817460-1640615049-2@sloti47n08>
```